# How to determine the class type of a sub-class in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML file with the following elements.

```
<productType>
  <productTypeX />
  <!-- One of the following elements are also possible:
  <productTypeY />
  <productTypeZ />
  -->
</productType>
```

So, the XML could also look like this:

```
<productType>
  <productTypeZ />
</productType>
```

The XML is unmarshalled to a POJO by using JAXB.

How can I determine if the child of `<productType>` is X, Y or Z? Either in the mapped POJO or directly in the XML?

Comment: Well after a succesfull unmarshall can't you just check which getters return null ? Or I did not understood the question.

Comment: @lazarov I __think__, it shall be unmarshelled as `ProductType pt = new ProductTypeN()` where N could be X,Y **or** Z ... correct me if wrong, Robert.

Comment: @lazarov That would be possible. I didn't mention that there are ten possible "product types", so this would mean a lot of "repetition" in checking which getter would return `null`. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: What **I** would do: One "ProductType"-Class having all the fields of the different Types + one Field to determine which Type it actually represents.

Comment: @Fildor Unfortunately these classes are generated based on a WSDL via `wsdl2java`, i.e. I can't control their structure.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So you have ProductTypeX, ..Y, .. Z from WSDL. And you have a "wrapping" class ProductType or is it an Interface to those X,Y,Z?

Comment: @Fildor Correct, the "base" class is `ProductType` with subclasses like `ProductTypeX` etc.

Comment: Well as I thought you can't change the structure of the WSDL. So in this case when the sub-classes are different objects and as I see they don't have @Required annotation so there could be only one of them or two or none or all ten. I do not think you have any choice and you have to check manualy. Except if there is some bussines logic that can help like : "There will be only one subclass in the response"

Comment: @XmlType-Annotation came to my mind ... but not sure if that is applicable here.

Comment: What does your schema and schema-derived classes look like?

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a way maybe not cheaper than *checking* *by hand* - writing `if` for every `GETTER` about sub-classes(`null == obj.getProductTypeX()`) but here it is:

Lets assume that you end up with `JAXBElement<ProductType> productType` when you unmarshall.

Now you need to end up with a `Element` (org.w3c.dom.Element) object. Which can be done like this:

```
DOMResult res = new DOMResult();
marshaller.marshal(productType, res);
Element elt = ((Document)res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
```

Now the interface `Element` extends the interface `Node` from which we can
come to a conclusion that we end up here with a `TREE` structure object and we can get his existing children like :

```
NodeList nodeList = elt.getChildNodes();
```

Now you can check the type and value of every `Node` but you have to check if the Node is an `ELEMENT_NODE` or `ATTRIBUTE_NODE` in most cases:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
    if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        currentNode.getNodeName();
        currentNode.getTextContent();
        //And whatever you like
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you or give you any directions how to get what you need.